# Unable to set UISlider's track tint to "absolute" clearColor

Tags: ios7, uislider

I am trying to set the color of tint on `UISlider` to clear (make it disappear). I am doing it the easiest way:

```
[self.seekBar setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.seekBar setMaximumTrackTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.seekBar setMinimumTrackTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

But I am getting this tiny graphical glitch:

[image: UISlider]

Is it a known issue or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions((CGSize){ 1, 1 }, NO, 0.0f);
UIImage *transparentImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[self.seekBar setMinimumTrackImage:transparentImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.seekBar setMaximumTrackImage:transparentImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.seekBar setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Glad to be of help :)